# number of conjugate class of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> find the number of conjugate class of $GL_3(\mathbb{F_2})$.

I was trying to using the fact that two elements are conjugate iff they are similar, thus I only need to find the number of non-equivalent rational form of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$. But I have no idea where to go on from this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you name a few rational equivalence classes?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez diagonal matrix with 3/2/1 one in the diagonal and other entries all 0? I don't know how to find all these equivalent classes.

Comment: Well, how many different classes are there which are diagonal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez isn't there only one with all 1's, because it is GL_3?

Comment: Well, before you mentioned that there is a class which contains the diagonal matrix with 3/2/1 along the diagonal. You should probably make up your mind :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez o okay :) so how to count the total number of rational equivalence classes?

Comment: Well, for now I am asking you to tell me how many diagonal classes there are

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I still think there's only one diagonal class because rank=3. Am I wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ are in the same conjugacy class?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez isn't that because $\begin{pmatrix} 3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$ det=0 under $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Ok. (Notice that that shows that the example you gave me in answer to my first comment did not give an example, as that matrix is not even in GL_3…) Can you name a conjugacy class which is not diagonal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez maybe $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Wha exactly is a rational normal form?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez from the definition there should be 1's in the sub-diagonal and real number in the last row...I can't see more things here

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez am I right? I haven't learn much about rational normal form and still don't know what to do here.